# What is topic.registered in ksql when running list topics

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb, kafka-topic

I'm using kafka-connect to stream the rows from a mysql table to a kafka topic.

When I run this on my ksql-client:

```
LIST TOPICS;
```

I get a list of topics looking like this:

```
Kafka Topic                   | Registered | Partitions | Partition Replicas | Consumers | ConsumerGroups
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
mysq-some-table               | false      | 1          | 1                  | 1         | 1
mysq-some-table2              | false      | 1          | 1                  | 1         | 1
```

I would like to know what is the meaning of `Registered`, it seems to be always false for all the topics created via kafka-connect.

I could not yet find anything in the documentation. I also noticed that as soon as I create a STREAM out of this topic, `Registered` becomes `true`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you're listing all of topics of Kafka.

Some are "registered" streams/tables of KSQL, the rest are not as they are plain Kafka topics not managed by KSQL.

Comment: As I mentioned in my question, I also noticed that as soon as I create a stream/table then the topic I used for creating the stream/table when executing "list topics" is marked as registered=true. I still dont understand what is the meaning of registered.

Comment: I think this answer helped me understand what you mentioned above: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50022332/1016425. Will add it to your answer and accept it